# Remote desktop is stuck on "securing remote connection"

Tags: azure, remote-desktop, rdp

Remote desktop is stuck on "securing remote connection". I am connecting to Windows 2008 VM on Azure from Windows 7. I have successfully connected for a few days before now. I have waited for over 15 minutes. I don't have local access to the server.

Comment: I had troubles with connecting to a VM from my company's network... Are you try to connect from the same location as your last successful attempt ?

Comment: Exactly the same location, same computer. It was OK the night before, this morning it just wouldn't connect.

Comment: Try to re-dowload the rdp from the Windows Azure Portal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that your Windows Azure VM is in **Running state** from Portal first and then try to RDP. Based on your error and experience, it is possible that your VM is not running or have some issue. Try restarting the VM from Management Preview Portal or using PowerShell and then try RDP and it should work.

Comment: Thanks. I restarted the VM eventually from the portal and it started working again. Of course, I lost the batch job I was running on it, which was why I did not want to restart it.

Comment: I had the same connection problem that forced me to restart the VM several times, it worked after a restart but then came back after a while. They disappeared when I changed from a small instance to a medium instance and then back again. Dont know why though?